Conditional HTML/CSS in Outlook Emails in Office 365
Microsoft Outlook supports conditional CSS, which enables developers to create markup and styling that will supposedly only render on Outlook.
For example, from Outlook conditional CSS, the following snippet is supposed to be hidden across all Outlook clients.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!--[if !mso]><!--> All Outlooks will ignore this <!--<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>

I tested this across a variety of devices and Outlook versions, and in every one of them, the text is still visible.
I do not have access to a Windows device so I suspect that might be the issue, but theoretically, this should work across all Outlooks, not just Outlook Windows.
I am using an Outlook account with the Office 365 subscription.
Screenshot from Outlook Desktop macOS 16.83.2:

Screenshot from Outlook Webmail Latest on macOS Safari:

Screenshot from Outlook iOS 4.2411.0:


You have a misunderstanding of this, which is understandable as the guide you are using doesn't spell it out. They are referring to the Windows desktop version.
Only the Windows desktop versions of Outlook use Microsoft Word as a rendering engine, and so only it has this conditional code.
You can browse through different ways to target other Outlooks here, noting it's very rare to actually need these for anything other than Windows desktop Outlook: https://www.howtotarget.email/

Super interesting. Thanks for sharing. However, after doing a more in-depth deep dive with EmailOnAcid, I found that their macOS Office Outook 365 is able to correctly process conditional CSS. See here: image.png. Does EmailOnAcid not really use macOS, or somehow force it to use the Word rendering engine?

What was the code you used? It's never been on the Word bandwagon, and never will be.

Super weird, right? I've updated my post to include code (also available on PasteBin https://pastebin.com/UFCYRLiN)

Sometimes these services chop off the screenshot a little at the bottom. You could test again using several lines, and see if it shows up.

Very interesting- this bug just dropped, where Airmail on macOS is interpreting the Outlook windows conditional comments. Now, that's a different program, but the first I've heard in the wild, and related to this thread: https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/138
